# Bundler error when I try to do bundle install Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

When I `$bundle install --without production`, I get this:

```
An error occured while installing nokogiri (1.5.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have some missing dependencies for native extension.
When you run `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.5'` it should output what is missing and you can fix it.

On Debian/Ubuntu you can also run following

`sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core      zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion`

to install dependencies commonly required by Ruby / gems. This might solve the problem for you.